# calling the onCreate method from the same class

Tags: android

Can I call the onCreate method of a particular activity from the same activity ? Like upon clicking a button ,I will create a new tab and I want to run the same code as contained by the onCreate method of the current activity again.

Answer (score 6):

`Activity#onCreate()` is a lifecycle method and should never be called directly by your own code. If you want to reuse a piece of logic, factor it out into its own method and call the same from both the `onCreate()` and the place where you want to reuse it.

Ideally, the setup code that an `Activity` requires to build and initialize itself should be run only once in its lifetime. So, placing something that also needs to be called on a button-click there, points at bigger problems with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but you should not. It would be better to move out the code you want to a separate method which can be called anytime you need within the activity. As pointed out it's a lifecycle method and it is called whenever the Activity is created or recreated.

However if you still want it you can call it by passing a Bundled data to the method.

```
Bundle configBundle = new Bundle();
onCreate(configBundle);
```

You can use the Bundled data to point out what the method should actually do.

Comment: Yes you can, but you definitely should not.  The only thing calling the life cycle methods should be Android.