# How to call onCreate methode in the same activity?

Tags: android, oncreate

I have a activity, named MainActivity. I want to recall the onCreate activity in this activity(MainActivity).

```
MainActivity.this.onCreate(....);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: This may be a case of "you don't want to do that" -- could you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve? Maybe someone can offer an efficient alternative!

Comment: You probably shouldn't do that, you should to respect the life cycle of the activity. If you need to refresh the activity you could use:
finish();
startActivity(getIntent());
but if you need to the an action that is inside onCreate(), the best thing to do is to create a method and call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can but you should not. You should mention your requirement. But if you want to execute the same code that is in onCreate then you can take out that code to separate method and call that in onCreate and from the place where you wanted to call onCreate from.

Find more info on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28133918/3209739).

Comment: Cool you could understnad the concept though it si very small.You may accept answer too.

Comment: thank you. I called it in seperate method.